# GridView with different 2 different itemtemplates that have 2 different sizes XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, gridview, windows-phone-8.1

I am using a DataTemplateSelector to select between two itemtemplates on a gridview in a WinRT Phone 8.1 application.  However these two templates have 2 different sizes one has a height of 80 pixels and the other one of 400.  When i try to use both of the template my gridview will only show me all the items but with only 80 pixel of height.

I have tried to add:

```
GridView.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <VariableSizedWrapGrid />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </GridView.ItemsPanel>
```

but it doesnt help.  If you guys could tell me in which direction to look that would be great!

My Gridview xaml:

```
 <GridView Name="EntityListbox"
                  Grid.Row="0"
                  SelectionMode="None"
                  VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling"
                  ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource MyAAAAAAAAATemplateSelector}"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding AAAAAA.Data,Mode=TwoWay}"
>
 </GridView>
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using a WrapPanel? You can create a GridView and by setting the ItemsPanel to WrapPanel, you can get WrapPanel your ItemTemplates

```
<GridView x:Name="GridViewElement">
    <GridView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <local:WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal"  />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemsPanel>
    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            Your data template here
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemTemplate>
</GridView>
```